# Reshaping an array to 2-D by specifying only the column size

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.x

I have a vector of length, lets say 10:

```
foo = np.arange(2,12)
```

In order to convert it to a 2-D array, with lets say 2 columns, I use the command `reshape` with following arguments:

```
foo.reshape(len(foo)/2, 2)
```

I was wondering if there is a more elegant way/syntax to do that (may be sth like `foo.reshape(,2)` )

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You almost had it!  You can use `-1`.

```
>>> foo.reshape(-1, 2)
array([[ 2,  3],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 8,  9],
       [10, 11]])
```

As the `reshape` docs say:

```
newshape : int or tuple of ints
    The new shape should be compatible with the original shape. If
    an integer, then the result will be a 1-D array of that length.
    One shape dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred
    from the length of the array and remaining dimensions.
```